# Mp4 Video not display in IE11

Tags: css, html, html5-video, internet-explorer-11

I have a background video in mp4 format. It works in Chrome, Firefox, etc but does not work in Internet Explorer 11.

https://vmegastar.com/mantenimiento-informatico-para-empresas/

To access the url click on "access as a non-secure site"

Answer (score 0):

I believe IE requires the H.264 or MPEG-4 codec, which it seems like you don't specify/include. You can always check for browser support by using [HTML5Please](http://html5please.com/) and [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/).... Both sites usually have very up-to-date information about support, polyfills, and advice on how to take advantage of new technology.